# How to change the @input value of child component when button click in parent component ( child component is in *ngfor loop )

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I want to change the input value of discount when i click the button.

```
//parent.component.html
<button mat-raised-button (click)="addDiscount(5)" >5</button>
<div *ngFor="let items of itemSelected">
    <item-box [quantity]="quantity" [discount]="discount">
     </item-box>
 </div>



 //parent.component.ts
    discount: number = 0;

     addDiscount(disc: number){
       this.discount = disc;
      }
```

Comment: if possible please create a stackblitz demo for the problem. From your code it seems changing parent property will pass changed value to each child component. if this is what you want then have a look for demo : https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-parent-child-interaction-child-in-ngfor?file=app/app-child.component.ts

Comment: @AbhishekKumar Thank you for your answer really appreciate it. I realize my mistake because of your codes. It seems that I have inadequate codes in my child component.( The discount input is in a formgroup so i need to pass the data to it )

Comment: let me put this as an answer for help for other users.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your code it seems changing parent property will pass changed value to each child component

```
<button (click)="addDiscount(5)">Click Me to Send Data to Child</button>
 <div *ngFor="let item of items" >
  <br>
  <app-child [discount]="discount" [childToMaster]=master 
  (childToParent)="childToParent($event)">
 </app-child>
</div>
```

**[Parent-Child-Interaction Code Demo showing changing parent property is accessible in all child components](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-parent-child-interaction-child-in-ngfor?file=app/app-child.component.ts)**